# Python - Compare two lists of dict and return dicts from one list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists, `a = [dict1, dict2, dict3]` and b = `[dict1, dict2, dict4, dict5, dict6]`

I want to create two more lists, with the dicts from both lists not found in the other. So they would be,

```
c = [dict3] and d = [dict4, dict5]
```

I have tried the following but it returns way to many dicts

```
for i, j in [(i,j) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(b))]:
    if cmp(b[j],a[i]) == 1 or -1:
        new_prods = {}
        new_prods = a[i]
        c.append(new_prods)  

for i, j in [(i,j) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(b))]:
    if cmp(b[j],a[i]) == 0:
        old_prods = {}
        old_prods = b[j]
        d.append(old_prods)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: May you offer example and result?

Comment: In your example, why does `d` not contain `dict6` also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple *O(n^2)* solution:

```
a = [dict1, dict2, dict3] 
b = [dict1, dict2, dict4, dict5, dict6]

c = dicts_from_a_not_in_b = [x for x in a if x not in b]
d = dicts_from_b_not_in_a = [x for x in b if x not in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using sets would make perfect sense in this case.

```
c = set(a).difference(b)    
d = set(b).difference(a)
```

You can convert the sets to list by simply wrapping them by list(c) & list(d)

Comment: Hi @wim. Yes, I have. It works. Here is an example.

`>>>a = [1, 2, 3]`                                                                                             

`>>>b = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]`

`>>>list(set(a).difference(b))`

`[3]`

`>>>list(set(b).difference(a))`

`[4, 5, 6]`

Comment: You are trying with *integers*.  Have you tried it with dicts?

Comment: Thanks @wim. You are right, my approach doesn't work with dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way to do it reusing a function:

```
a = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
b = [dict1, dict2, dict4, dict5, dict6]

def find_uncommon_elements(list1, list2):
    list3 = []
    for item in list1:
        if item not in list2:
            list3.append(item)
    return list3

c = find_uncommon_elements(a,b)
d = find_uncommon_elements(b,a)
```

Writing a function helps in the event that you have to reuse this again later with a different set of dictionary lists, without having rewrite the entire function.

This will return:

```
c = [dict3]
d = [dict4, dict5, dict6]
```

Comment: This also nice since in runs in linear time O(n).

Comment: I'm curious, what makes you believe that this runs in linear time?

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected. The "not in" in the if statement is another loop. So it runs in quadratic time.

Comment: Yup. One way to make it O(m+n) is to use sets for the membership testing. There may be other ways, but who knows for sure?